# While creating the Android Application using Android Kotlin, could'nt display map, even though the App is working normally

Tags: android, kotlin, location, maps

While creating the Android Application using Android Kotlin, could'nt display map, even though the App is working normally, the map is blank without any content in it.

Also tried by changing the Api key

```
package com.example.currentlocationexample

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {          


        mMap = googleMap

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
}
```

Code developed automatically after creating maps activity but does'nt show the map after running on AVD.

```
2020-05-29 11:23:31.146 8721-8791/com.example.currentlocationexample E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
2020-05-29 11:23:31.148 212-212/? I/hwservicemanager: getTransport: Cannot find entry android.hardware.graphics.allocator@4.0::IAllocator/default in either framework or device manifest.
2020-05-29 11:23:31.156 8721-8791/com.example.currentlocationexample E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
        API Key: AIzaSyAUhYTWyk24s2_73aD4BlvIuP_4UZP
        Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 73:E8:C1:5C:01:85:AF:F5:58:D1:28:B5:4E:E8:B8:08:18:F0:24:9C;com.example.currentlocationexample
```

Also tried using different API keys

Comment: what does the log says when you open the map activity?

Answer (score 0):

Login to Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com) and 
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.

Comment: Got the map after Enabling the Key

Comment: I'm suffering from the same issue at the moment. I enabled the API, took that key and inserted into Android Maps sample project (where it explicitly shows you where the key needs to be inserted) and I still get the Authorization failure message. 
I can't even find "Google Maps Android API v2" explicitly in there anymore.

Comment: This is what I see when I search for "Maps for android" on the [dev console](https://imgur.com/a/4hHXGVp)...

Comment: Check if API key is copied correctly or if API key has any restrictions